# WinRT - is it possible to create a service?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to create an WinRT app that would handle requests coming from phone in local/wifi network. Say for example, I already have a mouse app in phone (similar to [this](http://mobilemouse.com/)). I want to write the server app that would be on the PC/tablet that handles the requests from the mouse app in phone. So whenever I open the mouse app in phone, I can send a push notification which should enable the server (win 8 app) to handle all the subsequent requests coming from the phone app. Is it doable?

Normally, I would create a windows service for this but wanted to check if it is possible in WinRT.

Comment: WinRT is a UI concept; as with any UI application it would have to be run manually and continually running in order to respond to notifications like this.  WinRT apps are limited in what they can do in terms of interprocess communications.  a "Classic" Windows service seems more appropriate based on what you described.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say your best bet is [ControlChannelTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh701032). I haven't used it myself but based on its description it is designed to enable your scenario.

> Enables real time notifications to be received in the background for class elements in the Windows.Networking.Sockets namespace and other networking transports.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tested it myself but I would say it is possible. But only as long as your app is running in the foreground. If you switch to another app your app can't communicate anymore because the app is suspended.

Although you could have a look at "The Time" in the windows app store. It's a clock that refreshes the app tile every second (and the author blogged about it).

To connect to your app I would test [signalR](http://signalr.net/), heard good things about it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in the question. The issue is that WinRT app may NOT be in foreground. It even may not be running. So the idea is from the mouse app on the phone, I can do a push notification which should get the winRT app to open and handle all the subsequent requests being in "background" (say when a user is watching a movie and wants to use the mouse app, the winRT app should not come to foreground). So can we do this in WinRT?

Comment: That's not possible. You can notifiy you app via push but you have to open it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [StreamSocketListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR226906) class, but as [jwillmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639367/jwillmer) said, probably only as long as your application is running in the foreground.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in the question. The issue is that WinRT app may NOT be in foreground. It even may not be running. So the idea is from the mouse app on the phone, I can do a push notification which should get the winRT app to open and handle all the subsequent requests being in "background" (say when a user is watching a movie and wants to use the mouse app, the winRT app should not come to foreground). So can we do this in WinRT?